# Есть ли в java библиотеки, позволяющие эскейпить shell-токены?

Tags: java, bash, shell, jdk11, escape

Стоит задача выполнения различных операций по SSH. Например, записать текст по SSH в файл, используя

```bsh
echo userInput > file
```

Текст является вводом пользователя. Какие есть готовые решения, чтобы заэскейпить пользовательский ввод, дабы не возникло bash инъекции? В питоне для этого есть встроенный модуль [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) с нужным методом [shlex.quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote), для Java чего-то подобного не нашёл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что `shlex` написан на самом питоне (ожидал, что это скомпилированная C библиотека) и нет проблем посмотреть реализацию метода `quote`:

```py
_find_unsafe = re.compile(r'[^\w@%+=:,./-]', re.ASCII).search

def quote(s):
    """Return a shell-escaped version of the string *s*."""
    if not s:
        return "''"
    if _find_unsafe(s) is None:
        return s

    # use single quotes, and put single quotes into double quotes
    # the string $'b is then quoted as '$'"'"'b'
    return "'" + s.replace("'", "'\"'\"'") + "'"
```

Моя Java имплементация:

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Shlex {
    private static final Pattern UNSAFE_SYMBOLS = Pattern.compile("[^\\w@%+=:,./-]");

    private Shlex() {
    }

    public static String quote(String token) {
        if (token.isEmpty()) {
            return "''";
        }

        if (!UNSAFE_SYMBOLS.matcher(token).find()) {
            return token;
        }

        return "'" + token.replace("'", "'\"'\"'") + "'";
    }
}
```

Тесты:

```java
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class ShlexTest {
    @Test
    public void quoteUnsafeString() {
        assertEquals("'sp ace'", Shlex.quote("sp ace"));

        String command = String.format("ls -l %s", Shlex.quote("somefile; rm -rf ~"));
        assertEquals("ls -l 'somefile; rm -rf ~'", command);

        String remote_command = String.format("ssh home %s", Shlex.quote(command));
        assertEquals("ssh home 'ls -l '\"'\"'somefile; rm -rf ~'\"'\"''", remote_command);
    }

    @Test
    public void quoteSafeString() {
        assertEquals("string", Shlex.quote("string"));
    }
}
```